# Importing module provides SyntaxError

Tags: python, pygame, python-import

I have a module using Pygame and sys:

```
import pygame, sys

font = pygame.font.SysFont('sans-serif', 72)

class console:

    def text(self, surface, text, pos):
        text = font.render(text, 1, (255, 255, 255))
        surface.blit(text, (pos[0], pos[1]))
```

This module returns no errors of any kind. I also have a short main program designed to import and use the module:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
import pygame-console.py

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640, 480])

console = pygame-console.console()

console.text(screen, 'Hello World!', (0, 0))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
```

The main program returns a SyntaxError on the third line, like so:

```
File "C:\Python25\pgTESTimport.py" line 3
import pygame-console.py
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Script terminated.
```

I'm using Stani's Python Editor due to IDLE's difficulty with sys.exit(). Can anybody tell me what the problem is with this code? Why does it return SyntaxError on normal-looking code?

Comment: Dash means minus.  Python sees you trying to subtract a module name from a module name and gets confused.  Also, drop the `.py`.

Comment: That makes sense! I must be very tired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how you import modules, you do not need to give the `.py` at the end, also you cannot directly import modules with `-` in the name.

You would either need to rename your file to something without a `-` in it, like `pygameconsole.py` and then import it using -

```
import pygameconsole
```

Or, if you are do not want to rename the file, and want to keep the `-` in the name, you can use `importlib` to import it -

```
import importlib
pygameconsole = importlib.import_module('pygame-console')
```

Then you can use it using `pygameconsole` .

Comment: Thanks! I'm probably very tired, I thought I knew full well how to import modules, I'm no stranger to python. But I didn't know about importlib or that specific limitation of modules. Something all my books forgot to leave out... Thanks!